# How to design this shape in android

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, android-drawable

I want to make this shape,for that i tried layer-list to design such shape but it doesn't happen exactly what i want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/APP_PRIMARY"/>
            <corners android:topRightRadius="100dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:width="100dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:topRightRadius="90dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="90dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Output of above code is

[image: like this]

Desired Output.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: make customview using [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path).

Comment: go for custom view

Answer (score 0):

This is what you exactly want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <corners android:radius="90dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:width="100dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="90dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:width="90dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        <corners android:radius="90dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Inform me either it works or not. Thanks

Comment: It's not working. And by the way you can't set `android:width="100dp"` below 23 api.

Answer (score 0):

you can use horizontal linear layout consists of two views
the right view you can use this drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- The bottom layer is blue square.-->
<item
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/accentYellowCanary" />
        <size android:height="100dp"
            android:width="200dp" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:topRightRadius="50dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- The middle layer is green circle.-->
<item
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="150dp"
    android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

which will result :

[image]

and for the left one you can use

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- The bottom layer is blue square.-->
<item
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color= "@color/offWhite"/>
        <size android:height="100dp"
            android:width="200dp" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:topRightRadius="50dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```